# ObjectListView's TreeListView cell editing very very slow

Tags: c#, treeview, objectlistview

I am using a TreeListView (ObjectListView) http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html - and populated it with a number of items. 
 One of the columns I made editable on double click for user input. 
Unfortunately, the editing is extremely slow and going **from one cell edit in the Qty column (see picture further below) to the next cell edit takes about 5-10 seconds each time.** Also, the cell editor takes a while to appear and disappear. 
Below is the code I use to populate the TreeListView:

```
        TreeListView.TreeRenderer renderer = this.treeListView.TreeColumnRenderer;
        renderer.LinePen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick, 0.5f);
        renderer.LinePen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid;
        renderer.IsShowLines = true;

        treeListView.RowFormatter = delegate(OLVListItem olvi)
        {
            var item = (IListView)olvi.RowObject;
            if (item.ItemType == "RM")
                olvi.ForeColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
        };

        treeListView.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x)
        {
            var job = x as IListView;
            if (job != null)
            {
                if (job.ItemType == "PA" || job.ItemType == "JC")
                {
                     var rm = job.ItemPart.GetRawMaterial();
                    var subParts = job.ItemPart.SubParts.Where(v => v != null).ToList();
                    if (rm.Count > 0|| subParts.Count > 0)//
                        return true;


                }


            }

                return false;
        };


        this.treeListView.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x)
        {
            try
            {
                var job = x as IListView;
                if (job != null)
                {
                    if (job.ItemType == "PA" || job.ItemType == "JC")
                    {
                        var part = job.ItemPart;
                        var rm = part.GetRawMaterial();
                        var subParts = part.SubParts.Where(v => v != null).ToList();
                        var items = new List<IListView>();

                        items.AddRange(subParts.GetRange(0, subParts.Count).ToList<IListView>());
                        items.AddRange(rm.GetRange(0, rm.Count).ToList<IListView>());
                        return items;
                    }

                }
                return null;

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "ObjectListViewDemo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return null;
            }
        };
        var lItems= jobs.ToList<IListView>();
        treeListView.SetObjects(lItems );


        Expand(lItems[0]);
        treeListView.RebuildAll(true);

    }

    public void Expand(object expItem)
    {
       treeListView.ToggleExpansion(expItem);

        foreach (var item in treeListView.GetChildren(expItem))
        {
            Expand(item);
        }

    }
```

Here is a picture of the cell editing:
 
[image]

Why is the editing so very slow? Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I am stuck with the same problem! Would appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

In your delegates you're using linear searches and several list copies (also linear). And this is for each item. 
Bad performance is to be expected.

If you want to improve on this, you can pre-calculate the results instead.